# Store data on button click from odoo website

Tags: python, database, web, odoo, html

I want to store data into odoo database from the odoo web page. I have created a new page from the odoo website builder. It has a few input fields and a submit button. I want to store that field's data into a table in the database on click of submit button. Odoo documentation only tells how to read data from the database on to the web page but not how to store data from web page to the database. Does anyone know how to do this?

Below is my code:

Controller:

```
@http.route('/tasks/clocktime', type='http', auth='user', website=True)
    def clock_time(self, **post):
        task_pool = request.registry['project.task']
        task_pool.attendance_action_change()
        return
```

Template:

```
<form target="_self" action="/tasks/clocktime" method="post">
    <a class="btn btn-primary a-submit">Log In/Out</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After clicking submit button, you must route to a method. In that method you can use normal odoo functions like (create, write) to store the data into the database. 
you have to use request.registry['model.name'].method(......) 
where method is create/write based on requirement 
I am pasting the sample code from website_sale module, which will write the data into sale_order model

```
@http.route(['/shop/payment/transaction/<int:acquirer_id>'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
    def payment_transaction(self, acquirer_id):
        cr, uid, context = request.cr, request.uid, request.context
        transaction_obj = request.registry.get('payment.transaction')
        order = request.website.sale_get_order(context=context)

        if not order or not order.order_line or acquirer_id is None:
            return request.redirect("/shop/checkout")

        assert order.partner_id.id != request.website.partner_id.id

        # find an already existing transaction
        tx = request.website.sale_get_transaction()
        if tx:
            if tx.state == 'draft':  # button cliked but no more info -> rewrite on tx or create a new one ?
                tx.write({
                    'acquirer_id': acquirer_id,
                    'amount': order.amount_total,
                })
            tx_id = tx.id
        else:
            tx_id = transaction_obj.create(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {
                'acquirer_id': acquirer_id,
                'type': 'form',
                'amount': order.amount_total,
                'currency_id': order.pricelist_id.currency_id.id,
                'partner_id': order.partner_id.id,
                'partner_country_id': order.partner_id.country_id.id,
                'reference': order.name,
                'sale_order_id': order.id,
            }, context=context)
            request.session['sale_transaction_id'] = tx_id

        # update quotation
        request.registry['sale.order'].write(
            cr, SUPERUSER_ID, [order.id], {
                'payment_acquirer_id': acquirer_id,
                'payment_tx_id': request.session['sale_transaction_id']
            }, context=context)

        return tx_id
```

Comment: Thanks Shravan. Can you also post the xml code where a call is being made to this method?

Comment: you can refer in any odoo website* modules views folder. Generally in the form action attribute we will give the url like this eg: <form action='/shop/payment/'></form>, and odoo will look for the corresponding method which is routed to that url

Comment: I am having trouble calling function from button. Please see code in edit.

Comment: what issue you are getting.

Comment: The method is not getting invoked

Comment: have you imported the py file in __init__.py